# .load DIV de outro site e substituindo URL após o load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá, meu problema é o seguinte. Após fazer o load de um div de outro domínio, quero mudar as URLs destas imagens do div carregado, para meu dominio. Ex:

```
<img class="InfoBarSmallElement" 
src="http://exemplo.com/img.png" />
```

Mudando para:

```
<img class="InfoBarSmallElement" 
src="http://meudominio.com/img.png" />
```

Segue abaixo o script que estou utilizando para o .load:

```
<script>
$(function(){
var contentURI= 'http://www.exemplo.com/ .Div';
$('.Result').load('../system/getp.php?url='+ contentURI);
});
</script>
```

getp.php

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

Agradeço muito se alguem puder me ajudar, obrigado.

Comment: O carregamento é feito no PHP ou no Javascript? Dependendo da resposta a solução muda.

Comment: feito no Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, considerando que está sendo lido no Javascript, é possível fazer isso de várias maneiras:

1. Com expressões regulares

Esta opção tende a ser mais trabalhosa, afinal antes você tinha um problema (mudar o src das imagens) e agora você terá dois (mudar o src e usar expressões regulares). Felizmente o Javascript trata ER's como entidades de primeira classe.

```
function ajustaSrcER() {
    var expReg = /src=(("[^"]+")|('[^']+'))/igm;

    var texto = $(".Result").innerHTML;

    $(".Result").innerHTML = texto.replace(expReg, function(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, s) {
    return "src=" + p1.replace("http://exemplo.com","http://meudominio.com");
    });
}
```

2. Manipulando o DOM

Outra opção consiste em manipular o DOM (Document Object Model). Considerando que é possível utilizar a biblioteca JQuery podemos fazer assim:

```
// funcao que busca todos os img's e altera seus src's
function ajustarSrc() {
     $(".Result img").each(function() {
        var src = $(this).prop("src");
        $(this).prop("src", src.replace("http://exemplo.com","http://meudominio.com"));
     });
}
```

Em ambos os casos isso deve ser executado imediatamente após o carregamento. Isso pode ser obtido incluindo uma função na chamada de $.load:

```
$.load(" coloque a sua url aqui ", function() {
    // Acao a ser executada depois do carregamento
});
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado cara.